# Cannot set pdr_use_farkas option in Z3py

Tags: python, z3, z3py, z3-fixedpoint

When I try to set the fixedpoint engine to PDR, and I try to set the pdr_use_farkas option, I am getting an unknown_parameter error.

In particular, I am using the following options on the fixedpoint object:

```
fp.set(engine='1',pdr_use_farkas=True,unbound_compressor=False,compile_with_widening=True)
```

This causes the error:

```
z3.types.Z3Exception: "unknown parameter ':pdr-use-farkas'"
```

Using set_option doesn't help either. I tried

```
set_option(dl_engine='1')
set_option(dl_pdr_use_farkas=True)
```

and I'm getting "unknown option".

Where am I making the mistake?

I'm using Z3 4.3.1 64bit.

Comment: The parameter names have changed between versions as newer versions include a name-space mechanism for parameter names. The Python API has a method for listing parameter descriptions:

For example:

     fp = Fixedpoint()
     print fp.param_descrs()

prints the set of available parameters (permalink: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/r32)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter names have changed between versions as newer versions include a name-space mechanism for parameter names. The Python API has a method for listing parameter descriptions: For example:

```
fp = Fixedpoint() 
print fp.param_descrs()
```

prints the set of available parameters (permalink: rise4fun.com/Z3Py/r32)